# Display alert when processing PHP form when uploaded file name already exists in database

Tags: php

I have a PHP form that works great. It uploads a file to the server and then checks to see if the file name already exists in the database. If it doesn't exist the code continues uploading the file and inserting the data in the database. This all works great. What I would like to do is display an alert giving the user the option of canceling the form processing if the file name already exists in the database or overwriting the file if it doesn't matter. Any help would be very appreciated!!!

````
if (isset($_FILES["fileName"]["name"]) && $_FILES["fileName"]["error"] == 0){
    $myfileName = $_FILES["fileName"]["name"];
    try {
       $getName = $conn->prepare("SELECT fileName FROM firmware WHERE fileName = ?");
       $getName->execute(array($myfileName));
       $num_rows = $getName->rowCount();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
       die("141 Query failed");
    }
                
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        DISPLAY ALERT TO GIVE USER OPTION TO CONTINUE OR STOP FORM 
        PROCESSING
    }
}```
````

Comment: PHP works server side.  Javascript works client side. PHP can't do anything client side.  I don't think it can be done?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't 'resume' a PHP script.  You could get your requested idea to work, if you use a 2 step process.

Step 1: This will use the PHP script you posted. You will need a separate page with the form inputs/buttons asking the user if they want to continue, then submit the form.  When you get to here:

```
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    DISPLAY ALERT TO GIVE USER OPTION TO CONTINUE OR STOP FORM 
    PROCESSING
}
```

You would do this:

```
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    Save the returned rows as JSON in the $_SESSION.
    Use the header command to redirect to the page for user input.
    Die, end process
}
```

Step 2:  This is the part of your PHP script that handles the returned rows, when the user submits the response.  When this script runs you check the $_SESSION for the JSON you saved before.  If the user wants to continue then you process the rows then delete the $_SESSION.  If the user doesn't want to continue then delete the $_SESSION JSON and die.

Be sure to start the session for each script.

This is just an overview of what you would need to do.  If you have any questions just send me a comment.

Comment: Based off of your assessment CharlesEF, this is what I think I will do:  When creating a "new" record, the code will check to see if there is already a file with the exact name. If there is, the code will require the user to go back and give the file a new name. When "editing" a current record, if there is a file being uploaded, I will allow the file to overwrite the old one. This solution is not perfect but is a lot simpler. I really appreciate your feedback!!!

Comment: @RWRuth, If you let the user change the file name then you won't need to save anything in the $_SESSION.  In fact you could change the logic in your PHP script to handle this also.  This way you could use the same script for both pages.  Hope everything works out for you.